# Windows sockets

Tags: windows, sockets

Does windows closes idle sockets? I mean if I'm a client connecting to a service on Windows server, is it possible that Windows server closes the connection after certain idle-time?

If yes, how to change this behaviour, or at least change the idle-time value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior depends on the SO_KEEPALIVE socket option.  Here's [the MSDN page about it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740476(VS.85).aspx) After some further digging you can adjust the KEEPALIVE semantics with a WSAIoctl and the [SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS Control Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877220(VS.85).aspx).

I find, that if you control both ends, it is usually better to implement keepalive messages as part of the protocol used to communicate between the client and server instead of relying on SO_KEEPALIVE.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that depends on the protocol, implementation and perhaps server config.

[PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) has an option to prevent timing out of SSH sessions by periodically sending null packets to the server - I suspect this is a simply packet with no actual payload. Perhaps you could implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877220%28VS.85%29.aspx) you will find that the defaul keep-alive timeout is set to 2 hours. You are maybe able to manipulate this by using [setsockopt/SO_SNDTIMEO/getsockopt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740476%28VS.85%29.aspx)